# Windows phone 8, upgrade app with background agent

Tags: windows-phone-8

Help to understand what happens when you update the application with a background agent...

1. I have application for WP8 with background agent. User install
   app from store, run app and run background agent.
2. In new version of app I'm modify code of background agent, publish
   new version to store.
3. User upgrade app from store, but not run main application.

What happens in this case?

On the device, there is a new version of the application, but not until the background agent was restarted from the new version of the main application, in remembrance remains running and running an old copy of the background agent?

That is, the application renewed, but still works a background agent from the old version of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in testing.
After the application is updated the next time the agent starts a new instance of the agent of the background of the new version of the application.